# pgfgantt: milestone with two labels

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

Is it possible to modify the \ganttmilestone, such that it has (besides the label at north) a second, optional label positioned at south?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `label` in the `milestone` style as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{3}
  \ganttmilestone[
     inline,
     milestone/.append style={label={[inner sep=1pt]below:baz}}
  ]{Foo}{2}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I needed.